# Having a problem with my Reaction Time test in C# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Relatively new to C#, I have only really started coding with this language since January. For my coursework, I have to create a program that includes a reaction time test. Took me about a week to fully understand how the code should work and this is what I have made so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WonderWallsApplication
{
    public partial class ReactionTimeTestForm : Form
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        int TimesTested = 0;
        int ReactionTime1 = 0;
        int ReactionTime2 = 0;
        int ReactionTime3 = 0;
        bool ButtonPressed = false;
        int ReactionTime { get; set; }

        public ReactionTimeTestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnReactionButton.BackColor = Color.Red;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (TimesTested == 0)
            {
                ReactionTest();
                if (ButtonPressed == true)
                {
                    ReactionTime1 = ReactionTime;
                    TimesTested = TimesTested + 1;
                    ButtonPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else if (TimesTested == 1)
            {
                ReactionTest();
                if (ButtonPressed == true)
                {
                    ReactionTime2 = ReactionTime;
                    TimesTested = TimesTested + 1;
                    ButtonPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else if (TimesTested == 2)
            {
                ReactionTest();
                if (ButtonPressed == true)
                {
                    ReactionTime3 = ReactionTime;
                    TimesTested = TimesTested + 1;
                    ButtonPressed = false;
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }
            else if (TimesTested == 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your times were: " + Convert.ToString(ReactionTime1) + ", " + Convert.ToString(ReactionTime2) + ", " + Convert.ToString(ReactionTime3));
            }
            else
            {

            }



        }


        public void btnReactionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            stopwatch.Stop();
            btnReactionButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
            btnReactionButton.Text = "Your time was " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds+ "ms milliseconds";
            ReactionTime = Convert.ToInt32(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            ButtonPressed = true;


        }

        public void ReactionTest()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            btnReactionButton.Text = "3";
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            btnReactionButton.Text = "2";
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            btnReactionButton.Text = "1";
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            btnReactionButton.Text = "0";
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            btnReactionButton.Text = "Press this button when it turns green";
            Task.Delay(random.Next(3000, 10000)).Wait();
            btnReactionButton.Visible = true;
            stopwatch.Start();
            btnReactionButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
            btnReactionButton.Text = "Click Now!";

        }
    }
    }
```

My problem is that when I run my code, it runs the reaction time test 4 times instead of three. It does record all the 3 FIRST values but for some reason I wrote something that may cause it to run another time. Debugging the program, I think it has something to do with the first time, it will record the time, but will not count it as a press. I honestly have no idea how to fix this. Hopefully one of you can. I made a change for each if statement for times tested to add a time tested. For example:

```
if (TimesTested == 0)
        {
            ReactionTest();
            TimesTested = TimesTested + 1;
            if (ButtonPressed == true)
            {
                ReactionTime1 = ReactionTime;
                ButtonPressed = false;

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

But all this did was it performed the test 3 times, but it output "Your times were 0, x, x". X is just a number for the reaction speed recorded.

Comment: The reason why the event handler was fired 4 times is because the first time it is called in WinForms when the form first initializes. You can suppress the extra call by following this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150882/how-to-prevent-value-changed-events-from-firing-on-form-initialization-in-net

Comment: Which solution do I follow as there are many answers on this thread. Also, I'm not the best at understanding what you are saying. Can you please explain to me what's happening in more detail. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled following your logic.  Here is a simpler version of your code:

```
Random random = new Random();
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
List<long> timesTested = new List<long>();

private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {     
  stopwatch.Reset();
  for (int i = 4; i > 0; --i) {
    btnReactionButton.Text = i.ToString();
    Task.Delay(500).Wait();
    btnReactionButton.Invalidate();
  }
  btnReactionButton.Text = "Press this button when it turns green";
  Task.Delay(random.Next(3000, 5000)).Wait();
  stopwatch.Start();
  btnReactionButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
  btnReactionButton.Text = "Click Now!";   
}

private void btnReactionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (stopwatch.IsRunning) {
    stopwatch.Stop();
    timesTested.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    btnReactionButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
    btnReactionButton.Text = string.Format("Your time was {0} milliseconds",
                                           timesTested[timesTested.Count - 1]);
    if (timesTested.Count == 3) {
      MessageBox.Show("Your times were: " + String.Join(", ", timesTested.ToArray()));
    }
  }
}
```

Your program does have a major flaw though.  The user can click the stop button before it's green and when the button turns green, it will record the earlier mouse click.  You should either hide the button or disable it until the reaction is ready.

Answer (score 0):

`ReactionTest()` method returns right after the button background is turned green and the label changed to "Click Now!". The user does not have a chance to click the button before the `ButtonPressed` flag is checked for the first time, after the first `ReactionTest()` call - because the check happens without waiting (for user input). So you were right that the first time the click is not counted. And that's why another 3 tries are allowed.

The simple solution is to move most of the code from `button1_Click_1()` to `btnReactionButton_Click()` and add the `async/await` to `ReactionTest()` to prevent it from blocking the UI and queuing the `btnReactionButton` click events which would incorrectly count as valid clicks when `ReactionTest()` returns. `ButtonPressed` flag is unnecessary.

```
    public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TimesTested < 3)
        {
            ReactionTest();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your times were: " + Convert.ToString(ReactionTime1) + ", " + Convert.ToString(ReactionTime2) + ", " + Convert.ToString(ReactionTime3));
        }
    }

    public void btnReactionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnReactionButton.Enabled = false;

        stopwatch.Stop();
        btnReactionButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
        btnReactionButton.Text = "Your time was " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms milliseconds";
        ReactionTime = Convert.ToInt32(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        if (TimesTested == 0)
        {
            ReactionTime1 = ReactionTime;
            TimesTested = TimesTested + 1;
        }
        else if (TimesTested == 1)
        {
            ReactionTime2 = ReactionTime;
            TimesTested = TimesTested + 1;
        }
        else if (TimesTested == 2)
        {
            ReactionTime3 = ReactionTime;
            TimesTested = TimesTested + 1;
        }
    }

    public async void ReactionTest()
    {
        stopwatch.Reset();
        btnReactionButton.Text = "3";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        btnReactionButton.Text = "2";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        btnReactionButton.Text = "1";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        btnReactionButton.Text = "0";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        btnReactionButton.Text = "Press this button when it turns green";
        await Task.Delay(random.Next(3000, 10000));
        btnReactionButton.Visible = true;
        stopwatch.Start();
        btnReactionButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
        btnReactionButton.Text = "Click Now!";
        btnReactionButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

According to the hint given by @LarsTech I added disabling the button when appropriate.