# UPGRADE_WARNING: Event TextChanged may fire when form is initialized in VB

Tags: vb.net, vb6, upgrade, vb6-migration

When I upgrade VB6 to VB.NET, I met an warning at below:

> UPGRADE_WARNING: Event `textbox.TextChanged` may fire when form is
> initialized in VB

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150882/how-to-prevent-value-changed-events-from-firing-on-form-initialization-in-net

Comment: This is added to warn users coming from VB6 about a different behavior in NET. You have two options: Set a global variable to avoid running code in your event handler until you have finished your own initialization, or do not use the form designer to set the event handler, leave the event empty, then add the event programmatically using [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) again, after finishing your initialization

Comment: Third option is to use `If textbox.IsHandleCreated Then` at the top of the event handler, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151100/15639)

Comment: @MarkJ: That is only for the case where you wire up events in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning, there isn't necessarily anything to fix.  How best to fix it if it is a problem , is going to depend upon your usage -- you could check Page.IsPostBack, set your own boolean,  check whatever fails when it's called and then make changes so that it doesn't fail, change how you register the event, lots of choices.

I would recommend that until you have an actual problem, just delete the comment.  It's probably helped you as much as it can -- it has made you aware of a potential change in behavior, which you can keep in the back of your mind if you see a problem with the new behavior.

Comment: Personally I would leave the warning until I was done testing.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs: after a few hundred of them, I found them to be just noise.  But I guess it just depends upon what you are doing.

Comment: In that case I certainly agree! And I've seen that too, typically the same warning shows up over and over. Once you figure one out, the others probably will be dealt with the same way.